# Sylvester's Criterion: The proof of the "second derivative test" for the classification of critical points of $f:\mathbb{R}^p\to \mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, abstract-algebra, polynomials

In the book of *The Element of Real Analysis* by Bartle, at page 265, it is given that

> Le the real valued function $f$ have a continuous second partial
>   derivatives on a neighbourhood of a **critical point** c in
>   $\mathbb{R}^p$, and consider the second derivative  $$P =
>  (D^2f(c))(w)^2 = \sum_{i,j = 1}^p \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_i
>  \partial x_j} (c) w_i w_j \quad (21.18)$$ evaluated at $w = (w_1, ..., w_p).$
>
> i-) If P > 0 for all $w\not =0$ in $\mathbb{R}^p$, f has a relative
>   min. at $c$
>
> ii-) If P < 0 for all $w\not =0$ in $\mathbb{R}^p$, f has a relative
>   max. at $c$
>
> iii-) If P take both positive and negative values for different $w
>  \not = 0$ in $\mathbb{R}^p$, then $c$ is a saddle point of $f$.

and in the bottom of the page,

> The preceding result indicates that the nature of the critical point
>   $c$ is determined by the quadratic function given in $(21.18)$. In
>   particular it is of importance to know whether this function can take
>   on both positive and negative values or whether it is always of one
>   sign. An important and well-known result of algebra can be used the
>   determine this.for each $j = 1,2, ..., p$, let $\Delta_j$ be the
>   determinant of the matrix $$\begin{bmatrix}
>      f_{x_1 x_1} & ... & f_{x_1 x_j} \\
>      \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \\
>       \\
>      f_{x_j x_1} & ... & f_{x_j x_j} \\ \end{bmatrix}$$
>
> If the numbers $\Delta_1 ,\Delta_2, ..., \Delta_p$ are all positive,
>   the second derivative $(21.18)$ takes **only** positive values, and
>   similarly if the numbers $\Delta_1 ,\Delta_2, ..., \Delta_p$ are
>   alternatively negative and positive, the expression (21.18) takes
>   **only** negative values [...]

My question is that which "well-known result of algebra" is the author talking about ? and how can we prove this result in the book using that "well-known result" ?

Comment: [Characterization 4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive-definite_matrix#Characterizations). I don't really see the point of mentioning it.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descartes%27_rule_of_signs

Comment: @reuns I can see that $\Delta_i$ for any $i =1,...,p$ is a Hermitian matrix, however, I'm still not able to see how does $\Delta_is$ determine the value of $P$.

Comment: @ziggurism I don't see the connection to the thing that we are talking.

Comment: The matrix is symmetric, and the question is if it is positive-semi-definite, ie. its characteristic polynomial has all its roots real and non-negative, which is seen by the rule of signs.

Comment: @reuns why are we looking to the root of its characteristic equation ?

Comment: A real symmetric matrix $M = M^\top$ is diagonalizable in an orthonormal basis $M = P D P^\top,P^\top = P^{-1}$ and $D$ is real. Positive semi-definite means $D_{ii} \ge 0$.

Comment: @reuns Thanks for the copy-paste. I still don't se why we need to look the roots of its characteristic equation.

Comment: Because $D_{ii}$ are the eigenvalues of $M$, the roots (counted with multiplicity) of $\det(M-xI)$. Thus my first comment : the statement in your book assumes a knowledge of the spectral theorem which is unnecessary here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets denote $A = (\alpha_{i,j}),$ where $\alpha_{i,j} = \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_i \partial x_j}$. Then observe that the polynomial
$$P =
 (D^2f(c))(w)^2 = \sum_{i,j = 1}^p \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_i
 \partial x_j} (c) w_i w_j \quad (21.18)$$
can be expressed as

$$P = w^T A w, \quad \text{where} \quad w^T = (w_1, ..., w_p) \in \mathbb{R}^p .$$

Now, by the [definition](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PositiveDefiniteMatrix.html), the polynomial $P$ takes only positive values iff the matrix $A$ is positive definite.

Now by [Sylvester's Criterion](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SylvestersCriterion.html), the matrix $A$ is positive definite iff the determinant $\Delta_j$ for any $0 < j \leq p$ is positive, hence the first statement directly follows.

To show the second statement, we can apply the Sylvester's criterion to $-A$, hence we would get that

> $$\Delta_i > 0\quad iff \quad \text{$i$ is even} \\ \Delta_i < 0\quad
>  iff \quad \text{$i$ is odd}$$  iff the matrix $-A$ is negative
>   definite.

Hence the desired result directly follows.